# How to rewrite node module variable or function

Tags: node.js

I am using [node-linkedin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin) for linkedin authentication in my nodejs application. this module is perfect for linkedin auth in webpage, but when I want to authenticate user from mobile app, I get CRSF attack, because state params doesnt match. This happens because plugin automatically generates state param `stateIn = Math.random().toString();`. If it would be possible to set it with my own variable, everything would be fine. So is it possible to rewrite module variable or function with my own?

Comment: You can fork it on github, modify it accordingly to your requirements and let your package.json points to your repo. That said, I strongly suggest to fork it, modify it to make it more flexible, so that it can accepts parameters during the setup, then propose your patch by means of a pull request on the main project. The community will thank you for the effort. :-)

Comment: Thank you for this idea! Just did that, worked fine!